# What is the difference between the Hydraulic diffusion equation and the Richards equation in groundwater dynamics?

Tags: models, soil, groundwater, fluid-dynamics, unsaturated-zone

What is the difference between the Hydraulic diffusion equation and the Richards equation in groundwater dynamics? I want also to understand the difference between the different storage coefficients (Ss, S,..).

Both are differential equations:

**Diffusivity equation**: $$\ Ss. ∂h/ ∂t = −∇ ·(− K \nabla h) − G$$.(for Incompressible liquid)(the flux (q), source terms (G), the specific storage (Ss), hydraulic head (h)) ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groundwater_flow_equation))

**Richards equation** (headed based form (there two other forms of this equation)): $$C(h) . ∂h/∂t = ∇ · K(h)∇H$$ (specific moisture capacity C(h), (H) total hydraulic head, h is the matric head) ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richards_equation))

Aren't they supposed to describe unsaturated flow ???

Comment: can you write those equations in your question so we can avoid searching for it ?

Comment: Both are differential equations:

Diffusivity equation: Ss. ∂h/ ∂t = −∇ · (−K∇h) − G.(for Incompressible liquid)(the flux (q), source terms (G), the specific storage (Ss), hydraulic head (h)) (source:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groundwater_flow_equation)

Richards equation (headed based form (there two other forms of this equation)): C(h) . ∂h/∂t = ∇ · K(h)∇H (specific moisture capacity C(h), (H) total hydraulic head, h is the matric head) (source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richards_equation)

Aren't they supposed to describe unsaturated flow ???

Comment: can you include them in the question using MathJax ?

Comment: Voila, easy to use !